# React Router - Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm testing out [react](/questions/tagged/react) router and I created 2 dummy components. 
The home path works fine, but when I try to go to the `/second` path, it gives the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-GBZpdGedoBaq6YBC2+5oO7Dc8WC1XJ5EUI5Md05Lls8='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

The first component

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const First = () => (<div>Hello 1</div>);
export default First;
```

The second component

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Second = () => (<div>Hello 2</div>);

export default Second;
```

And the Layout component

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import First from './first.js';
import Second from './second.js';

class Layout extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
     };
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={First}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={Second}/>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
  }

const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, app)
```

HTML head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; connect-src * ws://* wss://*; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src * ; img-src * data:; font-src * ; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add "historyApiFallback: true" in your webpack.config. It worked for me.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: options.stats,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: './dist',
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the error by changing the imported COM's name because I use the WebRTCChane and the WebRTC, this two COM has a similar name, after changing it, I successfully compile.

Answer (score 0):

I added  "--history-api-fallback" to my package.json run scripts

{
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --history-api-fallback --hot"
}

Answer (score -1):

You could modify the meta tag in your index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 
connect-src * ws://* wss://*; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src * ; 
img-src * data:; font-src * ; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />`
```

Comment: I just tried it, and its still producing the same error. I updated the OP to show the head of the html as it is now.

Comment: The problem comes from the way babel in browser script works.
Because of CSP limitations on extensions you will have to transpile the jsx code with babel localy and only add the transpiled (js) file in your html.
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli/

Comment: You can **not** set or change Content Security Policy in the HTML `<head>` element. This would be a massive backdoor to circumventing the provided security of CSP.