# How to fix `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'` on going to a subpath in React Node Express app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My React app runs on Node Express, and uses React Router. Going to a subpath e.g. `/sub` works fine in dev mode served by `parcel`, but when run in production mode using `node ./`, I get error on page:
`Cannot GET /sub`

Console error:
`Refused to load the font 'data:...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

I tried setting CSP using `<meta>`, but then I noticed response header itself has: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'`

[This question about React Router CSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393337/react-router-content-security-policy-directive-default-src-self) is similar, but I don't use `webpack`.

So I tried installing npm module [`express-csp-header@2.3.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csp-header) in order to set it:

```
const csp = require('csp-header');

csp({
    policies: {
        'default-src': [csp.SELF, '*'],
        'font-src': [csp.SELF, 'data:'],
        'img-src': [csp.SELF, 'data:'],
    }
});
```

Here's the rest of `/index.js`:

```
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

Here's the React `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Header><App /></Header>} />
            <Route path='/sub' render={() => <Header><Sub /></Header>} />
            ...
        </Switch>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm using [`history@4.7.2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history).

Setting CSP in Express doesn't affect final header. When I load root, I don't see CSP in header. When I load subpath, CSP is still `default-src 'none'`. Did I simply use the package incorrectly, or am I missing some other configuration?