# Inline style not applied

Tags: reactjs, http, content-security-policy

My React Application returns since todays bild this error:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-3dQYuWNjYbcHqe4TYkl7xf9jytstrjZWLNUtcbU8uYg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I added this meta tag to my `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline';">
```

but same issue again. How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Also no effect has this in webpac config

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve('src/www'),
    publicPath: '/',
    port: 8080,
    quiet: false,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
},
```

same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router - Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393337/react-router-content-security-policy-directive-default-src-self)

Comment: @iamsaksham same issue but their sollution does not fix my issue.

Comment: You can **not** set or change Content Security Policy in the HTML `<head>` element. This would be a massive backdoor to circumventing the provided security of CSP.

Comment: How can solve the issue?